# Calculate flow in a pipe

Tags: fluid-mechanics

Is there a formula for calculating flow in a pipe using just the pipe size, pressure and differential pressure? I have tried using Poiseuille's equation, omitting the pipe length, but the answer was astronomic!

Comment: See https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/pipes-fluid-flow-pressure-loss-t_18.html and https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/pipe-velocity-d_1096.html

Comment: But if you show what you did and calculated maybe someone would spot an error.

Answer (score 1):

Poiseuille's equation could be ok, but for better results I would recommend [Darcy-Weissbach equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation):
$$\frac{\Delta p}{L} = f_D\cdot \frac{\rho}{2}\cdot \frac{v^2}{D_H}$$

- $\Delta p$ pressure difference
- $L$ pipe length
- $f_D$ Darcy-Weissbach friction factor
- $\rho$ fluid density
- $v$ fluid velocity
- $D_H$ hydraulic diameter (internal diameter in case of a circular pipe)

There is a [comprehensive wiki list of correlations for friction factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy_friction_factor_formulae#Table_of_Approximations) $f_D$, from which I have a good experience with the Churchill's. Calculation of pressure loss is straight-forward, but if you need to calculate flowrate from given pressure loss, then it leads to iterative approaches. One of them is using [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) from starting interval for flowrate between zero and flowrate calculated based on laminar flow where $f_{D, laminar}=\frac{64}{Re}$ ($Re$ is the Reynolds number). The real flowrate should be somewhere in between.

Astronomic results can be due to omitting the pipe length (it is effectively 1 in whatever units you are using) and/or using too big of a pressure difference for such length. You should check the applicability of the equation. From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation#Equation):

> The equation fails in the limit of low viscosity, wide and/or short pipe.

If you want to stick with the Poiseuille's equation, try to increase the pipe length or decrease the pressure difference.

Comment: This answer is correct, but it amounts to "no", and as such, it's unfortunate that "no" is not one of the many words it uses.

Comment: @DanielHatton 'No' would be very short answer. Although correct in general, I think it is not correct for laminar regime, where 'the formula' can be derived.

Comment: The formula can indeed be derived for the laminar case, but one still can't get a flow rate value out of that formula with only the input data OP specifies.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your assumptions you could use Bernoulli's equation. If the pipe is full and you consider incompressible fluid and ignore any pipe-wall friction, one form of the equation is:

[image: Bernoulli equation]

You can then solve for your unknown velocity at point 2 (so long as you know the velocity at point 1), and then calculate flow by Q = Av (where A = area of cross section of pipe).

See also here: https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/fluids/fluid-dynamics/a/what-is-bernoullis-equation

Comment: But if you can "ignore any pipe-wall friction", it's not really a pipe.

Comment: It is a frequently made assumption, and in the right circumstances a reasonable one since the effect of wall friction is not always substantial.

Comment: Flows where that assumption is reasonable do indeed exist, but I maintain that such a flow would not be a "pipe flow" - maybe an "entrance flow" or an "orifice flow".

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the inaccuracy is due to the fact that you have neglected the influence of the pipe length in the evaluation. It is noted in this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation) that Poiseuille's equation **fails "in the limit of low viscosity, wide and/or short pipe.** Low viscosity or a wide pipe may result in turbulent flow, making it necessary to use more complex models, such as the Darcy–Weisbach equation. **The ratio of length to radius of a pipe should be greater than one forty-eighth of the Reynolds number for the Hagen–Poiseuille law to be valid.**[9] If the pipe is too short, the Hagen–Poiseuille equation may result in unphysically high flow rates;...".

So, you might have inadvertently used a set of parameters that the resulting flow violates the limits set in the assumptions: "The assumptions of the equation are that the fluid is incompressible and Newtonian; **the flow is laminar through a pipe of constant circular cross-section that is substantially longer than its diameter**; and there is no acceleration of fluid in the pipe. For velocities and pipe diameters above a threshold, actual fluid flow is not laminar but turbulent, leading to larger pressure drops than calculated by the Hagen–Poiseuille equation."

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If we know the flow Q, we can solve the Hagen - Pouiseuille equation.

$$\delta p= \frac{128 \mu LQ} {\pi D ^4}$$
But you must take length of pipe into account