# Vertical pipe flow

Tags: fluid-mechanics

I want to know the flow through a vertical pipe when a valve in the bottom is opened (a disk is lowered as illustrated in the drawing)
I know the heights in the drawing and the diameter of the pipe.
[image]

I have tried to use  Poiseuille's law (assuming laminar flow). Where I get the following:

Flow:  <$Q_{pipe} = \frac{(p_1-p_2-\rho \cdot g \cdot h_{submerged}) \cdot \pi \cdot D_{pipe}^4}{128 \cdot \mu \cdot h_{pipe}} $>
Velocity: <$Q_{pipe} = \frac{(p_1-p_2-\rho \cdot g \cdot h_{submerged}) \cdot \pi \cdot D_{pipe}^2}{32 \cdot \mu \cdot h_{pipe}} $>

where: <$p_1 = \rho \cdot g \cdot h_{submerged} \quad p_2 = p_{atm}$>

However, using this I end up with an average fluid velocity of approximately 9000 m/s.

Can anyone help me set up the equations needed?

parameters:

<$\rho 1000$>
<$g = 9.82$>
<$h_{pipe} = 0.152 m$>
<$D_{pipe} = 0.102 m$>
<$\mu = 0.00141$>

the submerged height can vary in the range of 0.1 to 0.45 m.

Comment: Your result could be correct, depending on the input parameters. Could you add the values of all the input parameters? Also, did you use the right viscosity?

Comment: Sure, the viscosity is for 10 degrees saltwater

Comment: Have you checked if the initial assumption of laminar flow is correct?

Comment: No I have not but it cant be if I use the High velocity to calculate reynolds number ?

Comment: Yes, it is probably not laminar flow. If that is the case, you should use another approach. [This answer to a similar problem](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/51869/21214) may help.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that you are effectively using just $p_2$ instead $\Delta p$. The $p_1$ cancels out with $\rho \cdot g\cdot h_{submerged}$.

Comment: The water rushing into a pipe that's initially full of air will not be a straightforward pipe calculation. You'll have to account for some form of 2 phase flow with water and air. You could use the valve as the limiting factor and figure out the flow rate through the valve based on its Cv or Kv value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the pipe is vertical, the flow will have to overcome its height as well (if $h_{submerged} = h_{pipe}$, there should be no flow). So the proper pressure difference driving the flow will be:
$$\Delta p = \left(h_{submerged} - h_{pipe}\right)\cdot \rho\cdot g$$

If calculated flow is not laminar, you can use the approach from [this answer](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/51869/21214).

Comment: What if the submerged height is lower than the height of the pipe ? should I consider the gravitational force from the tank ?

Comment: @KSH In that case there would be no flow and you would just get water surface in the pipe at the same level as the connected body of water.

Comment: okay I see thaanks